# applicationWillEnterForeground cannot invoke to load ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to load a main viewController (ViewController) when App loaded. When app enter foreground again to display another viewController (ConfigViewController) but I tried it display the "ViewController" instead of "ConfigViewController", I don't know why and anyone can help, thanks.

**AppDelegate:**

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let notificationName = Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
}
```

**Main ViewController:**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myBlog = "https://www.example.com/"
    let url = NSURL(string: myBlog)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    // init and load request in webview.
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(request as URLRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    self.view.sendSubview(toBack: webView)

}
```

**Configuration ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ConfigViewController : UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(displayAlert),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
            object: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func displayAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Reactivate", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(alertAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: what did u try?

Comment: I run the app, it shown "ViewController" first time, then I click HOME button to send the app in background mode, and then I click the app again to call out. The app still show me the "ViewController" instead call the "ConfigViewController". I expect each time the app active, the configurViewcontroller will display again.

Answer (score 0):

In `applicationWillEnterForeground` your viewcontrollers are not on the stack yet. This WILL.

to handle your need, you can:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vcMainView: ConfigViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfigViewController") as! ConfigViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = vcMainView
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

However is importante to see if in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` your are not calling another VC.

Just to be sure, this code will call your ConfigViewController every time the app become active. If you need to handle where and when it must be shown, this is not the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks, let me try again.